# how to change text font-size next to the input type="file" button?

Tags: file, upload

```
<input type="file"></input>
```

how to change text font-size next to the input type="file" button with CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
   input {
          font-size: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S.
Tested on FF and Chrome.

Comment: Button font is also changing . I need to change only the font of the selected file

Comment: AHn sorry! Mmmh, i'm not sure, but with just css i think is not possible. But maybe i'm wrong! I will study!